# $_SESSION not working while successful login

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

index.php

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#login").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            email = $("#cs-username-1").val();
            password = $("#cs-login-password-1").val();
            if(email=='' || password=='')
            {
                $("#loginsuccess").html("<p id='red'>All fields are mandatory!<p>");
            }
            else
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    data:{"email":email,"password":password},
                    url:"login.php",
                    success: function(data) 
                    {
                        if (typeof data !== 'object') {
                            data = JSON.parse(data);
                        }
                        if (data.redirect) {
                            window.location.replace(data.redirect);
                        } else {
                            $("#loginsuccess").html('<p id="red">' + data.error + '</p>');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

login.php

```
<?php
    include("config.php");
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);

    $sql = mysqli_query($con,"select student_id from student where email='".$email."' and password='".$password."' and status='1'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) 
    {
        $results = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
        $_SESSION['student'] = $results['student_id'];
        if (!isset($_POST)) 
        {
            header ("Location: dashboard.php");
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo json_encode(array('redirect' => "dashboard.php"));
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => 'Wrong email or password or may be your account not activated.'));
    }
?>
```

dashboard.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['student'];
    /*if(!isset($_SESSION['student']))
      {
          header("location: index.php");
      }*/
    include('assets/db/config.php');
?>
```

In this code I am simply create login module. Here, what happen I am create login via jQuery where I have `login.php` file and I am storing `student_id` inside the session variable but when I redirect to `dashboard.php` and echo `$_SESSION['student']` then it throw an error i.e. `Notice: Undefined index: student in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\dashboard.php on line 3` I don't know why where am I doing wrong? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: where is session_start in your login.php file?

Comment: _Small Point_ `data:{email:email, password:password},`

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) attack. 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing, specially not using MD5() or SHA1(). 
PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't get the "small point" thing.

Comment: @VLAZ you dont need quotes around the object property names. To be honest I am not sure if its overly relevant

Comment: @RiggsFolly ah, OK. I thought you meant something else, like the names are mismatched or there was a literal small point somewhere or something. Since I couldn't figure out, I decided to ask.

Comment: @VLAZ Not a problem my friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please start the session in login.php file :

```
include("config.php");
session_start();
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$password = md5($_POST['password']);
```

Or put the session_start in config.php file